# Can electrons, nucleons be transparent?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms

As, we can see right through the transparent materials which are composed of atoms which are further composed of electrons and nucleons, does this mean that atoms of transparent things are transparent. Or does it involve some other type of physics?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what glass is made up of?

Comment: While we focus (pun intended) on _visible_ light, the fact remains that the visible spectrum is a really, really, really small slice of the full electromagnetic spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

What determines if something is transparent is whether the photons of the light gets caught by the material or not. This depends on the wavelength of the light.

Individual atoms can only absorb or emit particular wavelengths, so they will tend to be transparent to other wavelengths (think of most gases). For visible light most atoms are not very good at interacting with the photons since most photons have the wrong energy. There has to be a difference in energy level for one of their electrons that corresponds to the photon energy for something to happen.

But when you bunch a lot of atoms together they become able to interact with more wavelengths. In particular, in metals the outermost electrons become shared between all the atoms forming an "electron gas" that interacts strongly with incoming photons of nearly all wavelengths, resulting in a reflective surface. Non-metals also absorb (or reflect) light because there are more possible transitions of their electrons and there is usually one transition that matches the incoming photon.

Free electrons and protons do scatter photons ([Thomson scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_scattering)), but the effect is tiny and not anything one would see with the naked eye unless there was an enormous particle intensity. Neutrons are electrically neutral, so they are far more transparent (pure neutronium should be clear, although there are always going to be some protons around scattering light and internal quark charges may have an effect).

Comment: I don't know if I'd go so far as to say that neutronium would be clear, as there may be an eV-level phonon-exchange band in a large enough lump of it. Photons would couple to phonons via either the weak interaction or via interaction with the nonzero neutron magnetic dipole moment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the electromagnetic spectrum, see what a [small range of frequencies visible light covers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum)

[image: spectrum]

> Visible light (colored bands).

Transparent means transparent to visible light.

> As, we can see right through the transparent materials which are composed of atoms which are further composed of electrons and nucleons,

Yes we can for some materials/lattices.

> does this mean that atoms of transparent things are transparent.

Not in the way you imagine.

> Or does it involve some other type of physics?

It is the interaction of photons with solids.

In solids, the atoms and molecules are bound with electric and magnetic fields and the incoming light, which is composed out of zillions of photons, interacts with these fields, with various outcomes. In transparent material, which is your specific question, the photons interact minimally with the fields between atoms and molecules, keeping the phases of the light which is composed out of them, so that images are retained through the transparent material. So the interactions with electrons and atoms/molecules are only interactions with their fields. Transparency is the phenomenon of phases passing through without distortions.

This is the [classical refraction of light](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/refr.html). Direction of a light beam can change , but not its coherence .

If the photons scatter off the material incoherently, raising energy levels in the lattice or the surface, images cannot be transmitted. If they scatter elastically  off surfaces , phases will be kept and  images can be mirrored.